# Recreating Query in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am recreating some old Java code and remaking it with Spring Boot. I am attempting to recreate this query using the JPA interface commands but I'm getting stumped because of the 'join'.

The original query is:

```
select pc.procedureCodeId, PC.AMOUNTTYPE from Section s join SectionContents sc 
    on sc.sectionTitle = s.sectionTitle and sc.cdtVersionId = s.cdtVersionId
   join ProcedureCode pc on pc.procedureCodeId = sc.procedureCodeId and
    pc.cdtVersionId = sc.cdtVersionId and pc.benefitId = ? where
    s.sectionTitle = ? and s.cdtVersionId = ?
```

In the remake I have created 3 entities:

SectionEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECTION", schema = "BPDMOWNER", catalog = "")
@IdClass(SectionEntityPK.class)
public class SectionEntity {

    private String sectiontitle;
    private long cdtversionid;
    private String filingid;
    private String sectiondescription;
    private String defaultplanname;
    private Timestamp lastupdate;
    private String lastupdatedby;
    private String sectionheading;
    private String schedule;
    private String eocfilingid;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SECTIONTITLE", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getSectiontitle() {
        return sectiontitle;
    }
```

SectioncontentEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECTIONCONTENTS", schema = "BPDMOWNER", catalog = "")
@IdClass(SectioncontentsEntityPK.class)
public class SectioncontentsEntity {

    private String sectiontitle;
    private long cdtversionid;
    private long sequence;
    private String amounttext;
    private String amounttextspanish;
    private String amounttype;
    private Byte leaderline;
    private Timestamp lastupdate;
    private String lastupdatedby;
    private Long intoc;
    private Byte eocleaderline;
    private SectionEntity section;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SECTIONTITLE", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getSectiontitle() {
        return sectiontitle;
    }
```

ProcedurecodeEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROCEDURECODE", schema = "BPDMOWNER", catalog = "")
public class ProcedurecodeEntity {
    private long procedurecodeid;
    private String procedurecode;
    private String proceduredescription;
    private String proceduredescriptionspanish;
    private String proceduredescriptiondbb;
    private String amounttext;
    private String amounttextspanish;
    private String amounttype;
    private String procedurecodecomment;
    private String procedurecoderemark;
    private Timestamp lastupdate;
    private String lastupdatedby;
    private Long benefitid;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROCEDURECODEID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public long getProcedurecodeid() {
        return procedurecodeid;
    }
```

If anyone could help me out in figuring out how to implement this query using the @Entity classes and the @Repository interface.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create the association between your entities to make your Jpa repository query work.

**SectionEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECTION", schema = "BPDMOWNER", catalog = "")
@IdClass(SectionEntityPK.class)
public class SectionEntity {

    private String sectiontitle;
    private long cdtversionid;
    private String filingid;
    private String sectiondescription;
    private String defaultplanname;
    private Timestamp lastupdate;
    private String lastupdatedby;
    private String sectionheading;
    private String schedule;
    private String eocfilingid;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="section_contents_cdtversionid") // just your column name for the association
    private SectionContentsEntity sectionContent;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SECTIONTITLE", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getSectiontitle() {
        return sectiontitle;
    }
```

**SectionContentsEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SECTIONCONTENTS", schema = "BPDMOWNER", catalog = "")
@IdClass(SectioncontentsEntityPK.class)
public class SectioncontentsEntity {

    private String sectiontitle;
    private long cdtversionid;
    private long sequence;
    private String amounttext;
    private String amounttextspanish;
    private String amounttype;
    private Byte leaderline;
    private Timestamp lastupdate;
    private String lastupdatedby;
    private Long intoc;
    private Byte eocleaderline;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="sectionContent")
    private SectionEntity section;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="procedure_code_id") // just your column name for the association
    private ProcedurecodeEntity procedureCode;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SECTIONTITLE", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getSectiontitle() {
        return sectiontitle;
    }
```

**ProcedurecodeEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROCEDURECODE", schema = "BPDMOWNER", catalog = "")
public class ProcedurecodeEntity {
    private long procedurecodeid;
    private String procedurecode;
    private String proceduredescription;
    private String proceduredescriptionspanish;
    private String proceduredescriptiondbb;
    private String amounttext;
    private String amounttextspanish;
    private String amounttype;
    private String procedurecodecomment;
    private String procedurecoderemark;
    private Timestamp lastupdate;
    private String lastupdatedby;
    private Long benefitid;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="procedureCode")
    private SectionContent sectionContent;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROCEDURECODEID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public long getProcedurecodeid() {
        return procedurecodeid;
    }
```

If your association is not OneToOne or bidirectional just change that to your needs.

Then in your jpa query you should use it like this:

```
public interface ProcedurecodeEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<ProcedurecodeEntity, Integer> {
    @Query("select pc.procedurecodeid, pc.amounttype from ProcedurecodeEntity pc " + 
          "join pc.sectionContent sc " +
          "join pc.sectionContent.section s " + 
          "where pc.benefitid = ?1 " +
          "and s.sectiontitle = ?2 " +
          "and s.cdtversionid = ?3")
   ProcedurecodeEntity findByBenefitIdAndSectionTitleAndCdtVersionId(long benefitid, String sectiontitle, long cdtversionid);
}
```